# How to find previous appearance in a MySQL data base

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that contains entries by name, datetime and an id. I want to get the previous entry of data for the same person "Brian". In other words if the ID of the current row is 21 I want the previous time Brian appears in the DB. The datetime field will always be less in the previous appearance.

```
SELECT t1.*
    FROM myTable t1
    WHERE t1.name = 'Brian'
      AND t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
                     FROM myTable t2
                     WHERE t1.name = t2.name
                     ORDER BY t2.id DESC
                     limit 1)
```

But of course the above doesn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all I need to do is change the limit to 1,1. At least this seems to work in my case.

Comment: Yes, even that must work. It will be treated as LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 which will return 2nd value from order clause.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
  SELECT t1.*
        FROM myTable t1
        WHERE t1.Name = 'Brian'
          AND t1.Id < (SELECT MAX(t2.Id)
                         FROM myTable  t2
                         WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
                         )
        ORDER BY t1.ID DESC
        LIMIT 1
```

Comment: No joy!  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0193 seconds.)

Comment: @KeithDKaiser I have modified to meet your requirement, it should work now.